# Why does the kmltreeview.nodemouseclick fire upon creation of folders?

Tags: c#, events, google-earth-plugin

I have the following code to create a folder in the kmltreeview:

```
            var folder = ge1.createFolder("Mobiles");
            folder.setName("Mobiles");
            kmlTreeView1.ParseKmlObject(folder);
```

With this code for some reason the NodeMouseClick function is firing with the "Mobiles" node as the 'e' argument:

[image: CodeSnippet]

If I comment out the code the event does not fire.  If I add more folders those also fire the event.

(I am not clicking on anything - just F5 to start and let it run.)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NodeMouseClick event is fired when a node is added to the KmlTreeView as part of the tri-state check mechanism. This simulated click is used to check if a KmlContainer should be checked, partially checked or unchecked. When this state is set the NodeMouseClick event is fired, but the given button is none.

So, you can test to screen out this automated check easily by looking to see which button was pressed to initiate the click.

```
  var folder = ge1.createFolder("Mobiles");
  folder.setName("Mobiles");
  kmlTreeView1.ParseKmlObject(folder);
  kmlTreeView1.NodeMouseClick += (o, e) =>
  {
      if (e.Button == MouseButtons.None)
      {
        // no actual mouse click...
        return;
      }

      // handle user interactions
  };
```

Comment: Perfecto!  Thanks again Fraser.  You definitely rock.